# Remove public from url laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am working on laravel 5.4 project and want to remove public from url.Right now my url is localhost/project_name/public/login.
Please suggest me way remove public from url.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1: Rename File**

In first step it is very easy and you need to just rename file name. you have to rename server.php to index.php at your laravel root directory.

```
server.php

INTO

index.php
```

**Step 2: Update .htaccess**

first of all you have to copy .htaccess file and put it laravel root folder. You just copy .htaccess file from public folder and then update bellow code:

**.htaccess**

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes



RewriteEngine On



# Handle Authorization Header

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]



# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$

RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]



# Handle Front Controller...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/

RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Documentation : https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-remove-public-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: i have less than 15 reputition, vote cast but not public. Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot... i've tinkered around for about 8 hours by now, following different tuts. Your solution is the first one, working **completely** as I want!

Answer (score 2):

Create a new .htaccess file in your root and paste following code.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

ONE OF THE BEST SOLUTION